# Howto debug a .net dmp file in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

My service which is implemented as a windows service crashes on a customer server every 2 weeks +- some days.

- The service is written in .net (vb.net/c#)
- Compiled for any-cpu
- Without prefer 32bit
- .net Framework 4.5.2
- Runs on a server with 64bit cpu
- Visual Studio is 2017 Professional

Since i'm unable to reproduce the problem, i want to debug the dump file.

I did setup user-mode dumps on the server based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The following picture shows how i have configured the user-mode dump in the registry:
[image]

I can open this dump, but the only information i get is

> The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
>   [image]

If i then start debugging (Managed Only, Mixed and Native Only), the following error is shown:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEF3FB09AF (clr.dll) in FooService.exe.3616.dmp: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
>   [image]

Any hint what i need to do in order to get more information out of the .dmp file?

Comment: [Configure debugging symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/) and verify they're loaded in the output window, then check the call stack of the exception for signs of your code. What you're seeing now is the bottom-most point of the stack, where it's effectively hit a `NullReferenceException` -- not very informative on its own, especially without symbols for `clr.dll`.

Comment: As far as i understand does visual studio download the symbols during the debug startup. I also already set the path to my debuggin symbols(pdb files).

Comment: I don't think you can continue the execution with dmp file. Its meant for you to analyze the current state of the application when it crashes. 0x0 basically is null so you are having a null ref exception

Comment: Yes, i get this. But i would like to see a stack trace or something to get a hint of where the exception happens. Besides this, it seems a .net application should not die like this usually.

Comment: @Manuel, Please disable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General, and then debug it again, you could get the Exception option "View Detail",  maybe you could get much more information. Access violation reading location 0x00000000 generally means that you're de-refrencing a pointer that hasn't been initialized and therefore has garbage values. So maybe you could debug your source code if you really want to find where the exception generated.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT, Same behaviour as before. There is not even a "View Detail" button.

Comment: @Manuel, Do you enable the Exception settings window under debug menu and the option "Use the new Exception Helper" under Tools->Option->Debugging? View it again. Like this document here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki/Debugging-Stack-Traces-from-Crash-Dumps, could you double click the call stack in the call stack window now?

Comment: I still get the same error. But one more (basic) question: Do the assemblies which run on the server which produces the dump file have to be compiled in debug mode already? Or can i use release compiled assemblies on the server which just have "Generate debug info" set to full?

Answer (score 2):

I guess i do now understand (more or less).

I did not save the pdb files used during the compilation of the release mode files, and tried to recreate those pdb files based on the same source, and this seems not to work for debugging the minidump in visual studio.

But with the [Debug Diagnostic Tool v2 Update 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) from from microsoft, i was able to get the Stack Trace of the exception based on my already existent minidump, and i'm now able to locate the error.

I still don't understand why visual studio can't show the same information.